# How would I make this simpler?

Tags: r

Edited:

I have working code below that reads in each file and merges them individually. I use this same code block about three x's.

Currently it re-orders the column for each read in. How would I be able to loop through and reorder all columns at once?

```
# Merge/Rearrange 
cr <- collds_r %>% unite(Contact_Name,Contact,...2, sep = " ") %>% 
  select(`Contact Company`,Contact_Name,`Contact Title`,Office,`Primary Practice`,
         everything(vars = NULL))
```

Comment: what part exactly do you wish to shorten?

Comment: @gaut I guess the way to re-order for each sheet. Wouldn't I be able to just rename then say re-order in bulk? Or is that wishful thinking?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you want feedback on code that works, maybe try a site like [codereview.se] instead. Otherwise focus your post on one specific question that doesn't depend on a subjective definition of "simpler" where different people can have different opinions

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks I'll do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one simple solution could be to read all excel files at once, then loop over the list of data frames.

```
library(readxl)
files <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)


for(i in 1:length(df.list)) {
  ## do the renaming here
    dat <- df.list[[i]]
    colnames(dat)[colnames(dat) %in% c("Product(s)...7",
                                       "Service Line(s)...8")] <- c("Product(s)",
                                                                    "Service Line(s)")
  }
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, I see your logic. Thanks for taking the time to explain :)

Comment: if the answer is satisfactory please mark it as the accepted answer